# Construct date at same time from existing datetime-local string

Tags: javascript, time, timezone-offset

I have an HTML page with an `<input type="datetime-local">` on it. This input has a value.

I want to construct a new date/time string, that is compatible with `datetime-local` format, representing the same time on today's date. Let's say that the current value is `'2022-12-01T12:00'`, and the current date is December 8th; I'd like to construct a value of `'2022-12-08T12:00'`.

My original approach was:

```js
const inpValue = '2022-12-01T12:00'
const now = new Date
const newDate = new Date(inpValue) // Thu Dec 01 2022 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
newDate.setDate(now.getDate())     // Thu Dec 08 2022 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

// This format is not accepted by datetime-local
newDate.toISOString()  // "2022-12-08T19:00:00.000Z"

// Simply chopping off the end of the string gives the wrong local time
newDate.toISOString().substr(0,16) // "2022-12-08T19:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63138883) we can use a large amount of custom formatting followed by string replacement:

```js
const newDate = new Date(inpValue)
newDate.setDate((new Date).getDate())
const goodTime = newDate.toLocaleString("sv-SE", {
    year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit",
    hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"}).replace(" ", "T"));
```

In the end, I think it is easier to just manipulate the fixed-length strings directly:

```js
const goodTime = (new Date).toISOString().substr(0,10) + inpValue.substr(10)
```

This answer may be off by one day if you call it when the date in UTC is ahead of or behind your local date. I will happily accept an alternative answer that is correct and sufficiently elegant and terse.